# Result Filter in wep api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

There is a filter called `ResultFilter` in `asp.net mvc` , is there any filter in wep api that corresponds to `Result filter` of asp.net mvc? Or how can i write a filter that runs just before return statement of every api controller method?

Answer (score 0):

> Or how can i write a filter that runs just before return statement of
>   every api controller method?

Unless you could do IL weaving (i.e. injecting IL during post-compilation), there's no way to do something before *return statement*.

What you're looking for is [`ActionFilterAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx), which has *before* and *after* virtual method flavors to override and provide behavior before an API controller action is going to be executed and after it has been already executed.

Finally, you can also implement a custom [`IHttpActionResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.ihttpactionresult(v=vs.118).aspx) to customize/build HTTP responses.